# Get component template by Name through content delivery API

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, odata, api

On the content delivery side I have filtered my components using metadata query, and now I have a list of components that need to be displayed. To get from component to component presentation next step is to choose CT.

As CT Id's will be different across environments, I would like "not to hardcode" id, but instead find CT "by Name".

This is possible through OData

```
...odata.svc/Templates?$filter=PublicationId eq 5 and Title eq 'Top News'
```

so the question is, can it be done through API ?

Comment: It definitely can be done... Can't look it up now, don't we have a TemplateTitleCriteria or something like that?

Comment: Can't do it. Tried to solve this for the DD4T Smart Target integration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get CT Title and custom metadata in DD4T for a DCP?](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7762/how-to-get-ct-title-and-custom-metadata-in-dd4t-for-a-dcp)

Comment: Hmm. I can get the list of Component Templates... but not their titles. OK, definitely jumped the gun on this one.

Comment: @NunoLinhares: After trying couple of possible ways, I got solution to retrieve component templates by their titles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After going through all possible API's, I got a solution to retrieve component template based on component template names.

Mainly you need to use `ItemTitleCriteria` to retrieving the component templates by names.

Thanks to **@NickoliRoussakov** for the clue given.

```
    using (ItemTypeCriteria mItemTypeCriteria = new ItemTypeCriteria(32))
    {
        using (ItemTitleCriteria mItemTitleCriteria = new ItemTitleCriteria("My Component Template"))
        {
            using (PublicationCriteria mPublicationCriteria = new PublicationCriteria(123))
            {
                AndCriteria mTitleCriteria = CriteriaFactory.And(mItemTypeCriteria, mItemTitleCriteria);
                AndCriteria mTemplateCriteria = CriteriaFactory.And(mTitleCriteria, mPublicationCriteria);
                Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.IItem[] result = new Query(mTemplateCriteria).ExecuteEntityQuery();

                if (result.Any())
                {
                    Tridion.ContentDelivery.Meta.IItem template = result.FirstOrDefault();
                    String templateTitle = template.Title;
                    String templateId = template.Id.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

***Note that above solution might have performance impact. Please test it throughly before using.***

Better option would be, by maintaining Component Template ID's in a configuration file with all the required template id's according to the environment and retrieve the component presentations.

Comment: Yep. Take a look at this Q&A.  It is basically the same question: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7762/how-to-get-ct-title-and-custom-metadata-in-dd4t-for-a-dcp

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov: Thanks for the clue. To achieve OP criteria, we need to use `ItemTitleCriteria`

Comment: @Siva, it seems that ItemTitleCriteria is replacing missing TemplateTitleCriteria nicely. This is exactly what I need. Tnx